# How to send client IP from a BFF to actual service?

Tags: node.js, express, networking, axios

We are building a BFF (Backend for Fronted) for our mobile app using Node JS and Express. 
Currently the mobile client makes an API call to the endpoints in the BFF which in turn calls the actual service, let's say "Service A". We use Axios as the HTTP client for making API calls to the Service A.

On every request from mobile client, the BFF receives the client IP. But I am unable to figure out a way to send the client IP from the BFF to the "Service A". The Service A always receives the BFF's IP address as the requester's IP address. I have tried sending the `x-forwarded-for` header from Axios by setting this header value manually, but without any success.

Can someone please guide me through a proper approach to send the mobile client IP address to Service A via the BFF? I haven't seen any place where we programmatically set the `X-Forwarded-For` header. So is it even a correct way to send this value as the header? Or is there a way to configure the express server to send the proper headers such that the Axios client sends the proper details.

Comment: Did you later find solution for this?